# How to integrate a erc20 token function, to make transfer token and check balance?

Tags: token, ethereum, erc20, web3-java

Im using java, web3j library, i am able to create wallet and integrate sendTx and balance checking function with ethereum, but i want to send erc20 token out of it, how can i accomplish it?

Comment: Do you have your own ERC20 token or do you want to use existing one?

Comment: https://github.com/web3j/web3j#working-with-smart-contracts-with-java-smart-contract-wrappers

Comment: thanks you guys, i still learning the web3j java wrapper class, i had successfully called balanceof method, i think thats the way to do it, still in progressing myself

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/blk-io/erc20-rest-service it has some good examples of how to interact with an ERC20 token using the wrapper classes. It also exposes some simple endpoints to enable you to interact with erc20 tokens using http requests.